# Is it possible to combine two different Template.php functions?

Tags: 7, theming

How about two different functions like below? Is it possible to combine below two Drupal Template.php functions?

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars)
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view)

Example:
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
if some field has option 1 selected
}
AND
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {
if a view is empty { attach alternative view}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this inside the views_pre_render

```
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    if ($node = menu_get_object()) { // gets current page node object
      $field_name_val = $node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; // get field value
      if ($field_name_val == 'option 1') {
        // your empty view code conditional goes here
        // if($view->result...
      }
    }
  }

}
```

You can find out the `current_display` name look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

Comment: I've tried below with Profile2 field but it's breaking my site. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below with a Profile2 field but it seems like Drupal doesn't like it..

```
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == ‘view_name’ && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {

    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user, 'main');
    $field_name_val=$profile->field_custom[‘und'][0]['value']

        if ($field_name_val == ‘0’) {

                if (empty($view->result)) {
                    $attachment = views_embed_view(‘view_name’’, ‘page_2’);
                    $view->attachment_after = $attachment;
            }
        }

        if ($field_name_val == ‘1’) {

                if (empty($view->result)) {
                     $attachment = views_embed_view(‘view_name’’, ‘page_3);
                     $view->attachment_after = $attachment;
            }
        }
}
}
```